# UPDATED:JQGrid with pager, table ID of last row repeating once when the row number is increased

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, duplicates, row, pager

I have a (weird ?) problem with JQGrid. I am populating the grid with local XML. I have set a JQGrid with rowNum:10 and rowList:[10,20,30,40,50].
I have 12 records.
The data (initially 10) is loaded perfectly in the grid and the table IDs are ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]. When I change the rowList to 20, the table IDs are ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "10", "11"]. The number 10 is shown twice.
Have anybody seen this error before ?
Thanks in advance.

**JQuery version: 1.4.2

jqGrid version : 3.8.1**

**Code Snippets**
The xml we have here is :

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><root><rows><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row><row><cell>prasanth</cell><cell>kumar</cell></row></rows></root>

The JQGrid is defined by the following code:

```
    jQuery("#tableGrid").jqGrid(
    { 
        datatype: "xmlstring",
        datastr : mystr, 
        height: 'auto', 
        rowNum: 10, 
        rowList: [10,20,30,40,50], 
        colNames:['First Name', 'Last Name'], 
        colModel:[ {name:'firstname', width:7, sorttype:"string"},
                   {name:'lastname', width:7, sorttype:"string"}       
                 ], 
        pager: "#pager", 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortname: 'firstname', 
        autowidth:true,
        grouping:false
    });
```

When I check in firebug after changing the rowlist to 20, the rows are created as below:

```
<tr id="9" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row">

<tr id="10" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row">

<tr id="10" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row">
```

Note that the <tr id="10"> is repeating. This happens when I put the rowNum as 10. If I change the rowNum to 3, the <tr id="3"> will be created twice.

Comment: You should include full information needed to reproduce your problem: the XML data and the JavaScript code which create and fill jqGrid are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem is that you don't include the `id` information in the data which you posted. Moreover you use "retro" versions of jQuery and jqGrid. I recommend you to use jQuery 1.6.2 and jqGrid 4.1.2. Starting with the version 3.8.2 was introduced $.jgrid.randId() method which are used currently in many places. I hope that the problem are already fixed in the last version of jqGrid.

In any way if you would add `id` attribute to the `<row>` element of your data the problem should not exist even if you would continue to use old version of jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, by setting the id attribute for <row> the issue is resolved. I will upgrade the version of jQuery and jqGrid and see if that too helps.